# Selecting a href attribute of a link using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, attributes, href

I have the following code that is not working properly, what am I doing wrong???

```
$('#gallerynav ul li a').click(function(){
    var href = $('#gallerynav ul li a').attr('href')
    $("#galleries").children().fadeOut(500 , function(){
        (href).fadeIn(500)
    })
})
```

I have the href of the links set like this:

```
<div id="gallerynav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#foo">link</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what you expect to happen when this code runs. If there is another element with ID="foo" then wows is probably correct.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
$('#gallerynav ul li a').click(function(){        
    var link = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $("#galleries").children().fadeOut(500 , function(){
        $(link).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: this looks right, corrects the problem where the variable is not created with the correct object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#gallerynav ul li a').click(function(evt) {
    var href = this.href;
    $("#galleries").children().fadeOut(500 , function() {
        $(href).fadeIn(500);
    });
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a $ in front of the (href) call. Try:

```
$(href).fadeIn(500)
```

Comment: var href will contain the string "#foo" this will be treated like a selector and won't match anything. (nothing in the example anyway) if there is some more markup with the ID="foo" then this looks right.

Answer (score 0):

I think: `var href = $('#gallerynav ul li a').attr('href');`

should be: `var href = this.attr('href');`